# lightning:formattedDateTime issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ui

Today I noticed one awkward behavior of   `**<lightning:formattedDateTime>**`  aura component.

Examples:

I have a component where I need to display today date like Nov 5, 2019

But when i use `**<lightning:formattedDateTime>**`  its display the 1 Day behind Nov 4, 2019

and when i use  `**<ui:outputDate>**` Its showing perfect date Nov 5, 2019

This happens only when I'm in the **US timezone** only.

Is it anybody face this type of issue or its a bug in ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the "timezone" attribute of lightning:formattedDateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `ui:outputDate` shows time in UTC, but `lightning:formattedDateTime` shows time based on `runtime environment's time zone` which will be different based on location. If you want this to be specific time zone then you can set that using `timeZone` attribute of `lightning:formattedDateTime`.

> The time zone to display. Use this attribute only if you want to
>   override the default, which is the runtime environment's time zone.
>   Specify a time zone listed in the IANA time zone database
>   (https://www.iana.org/time-zones). For example, set the value to
>   'Pacific/Honolulu' to display Hawaii time. The short code UTC is also
>   accepted.

This is how you can specify time zone.

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="1547250828000" timeZone="UTC" />
```

Which will show you an exact time as in `ui:outputDate`.

If you want American time zone then below code should work for you.

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="1547250828000" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"  hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" timeZoneName="short" timeZone="America/New_York" />
```

> Please note that `ui:outputDate` is **Deprecated** as of API version 47.0. Use lightning:formattedDateTime instead.

Please refer for more details.

[lightning:formattedDateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/documentation)

[ui:outputDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:outputDate/specification)